# Mechanics of a rolling drum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image: image_of_problem]

I have no clue on how to approach this. The professor only discussed centripetal acceleration and angular velocity (As in $2πr\over T$ $= ωr$). Does the acceleration along the axis of the drum act in the same way that centripetal acceleration does? I understand that the angular velocity in this case is $ωR$, and the derivative of that is the angular acceleration, but how to I find $ω$? How does $a$ affect the period, and how does its position (In this case along the axis) affect that?

Comment: You have been given a translational acceleration of $a$. You just need to relate this to the angular version $\alpha$. How can we relate the two?

Comment: That's what I don't know, since the acceleration is along the axis of the drum. Also, surely the gravitational acceleration must act uniformly along _all_ of the drum, not just that one spot, i.e. there's acceleration at the very top as well as along the side of the drum.

Comment: Here's a hint: what is the relationship between $v$ and $\omega$? Think about where this comes from. Sure it acts on the entire drum, but the drum has symmetry so we can consider the gravitational acceleration through the center of mass. Anyway that's not the problem. You have been *given* an acceleration $a$, yes you know it's due to gravity but it doesn't matter where is comes from, you know its value.

Comment: Would you know what to do if you were given the acceleration of the edge of the drum with respect to the center?

Comment: Not sure. We've only worked with centripetal acceleration in class, where the tangential velocity has remained constant.

Well, I know that $v^2/R = ω^2*R$.

Comment: Ok, I searched around some more, and I found out that the angular acceleration is, when the acceleration in tangential:
$α = a/r$, but what when the acceleration is along the axis like in this example?

Comment: Great, hopefully you understand where that relationship is coming from? So we want to know the acceleration of the **edge**. Now, if the cylinder's center has acceleration $a$ with respect to the slope, how is the bottom edge accelerating with respect to the center of the cylinder?

Comment: Yea, I understand where it's coming from, both intuitively and formally. I just find it weird that the book or the professor doesn't even mention that, I'm taking a more mathematically rigorous course, but that's because Physics is difficult for me whilst math isn't.

Anyhow, then the bottom edge should be accelerating in the opposite direction, or $-a$, right?

Comment: Right, so the edge is accelerating with magnitude $a$ with respect to the center and you can now find $\alpha$.

Comment: Is this true of all motion in which a circle or cylinder is moving? E.g, another problem had a wheel of a car rolling straight without slipping with constant velocity $v$. Does that mean that if a pebble got stuck on the edge of the wheel it would have the _speed_ $v$ and direction tangential to the wheel?

Comment: Yes, *with respect to the center of the wheel*. The speed of the edge of the wheel with respect to the ground depends on which part of the wheel you are looking at. For example, the bottom isn't moving with respect to the ground, the top would be moving with speed $2v$. If you have further questions you should ask them as a separate question :).

Answer (score 1):

There is no oscillation or period on this problem. All you know is the slip condition which means that the center of the drum moves by $v = \omega R$.

Now differentiate this relationship to find $a$ as a function of $\alpha = \dot{\omega}$.